# Failed to download repository information ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, repository

Hi I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04, when checking for updates I get the "Failed to download repository information"("Check internet connection") message, though when I press OK it allows to to install other updates, so my question is why do I get this error message and how can I fix it? Another issue I have is sometimes my system freezes(turns black & white) for a few seconds sometimes minutes pus I notice my PC is very slow sometimes, I also see this when i check my HDD "Disk is OK, 2 bad sectors (35° C / 95° F)".. Not sure if all these problems are related to the "failed to D/L Repository info" message, if not, any help/suggestions or info on any or all of these problems would be appreciated.. NOTE: I do have a lot of software installed like steam, wine, utorrent, etc.. and some web/software dev tools besides the partitions it says I’m only using close to 18% of my HDD.. Anyone please help if you need more info plz let me know.. oh btw I think I originally installed V.14.04 via bootable stick then upgraded to 15.04 through software updater.. if this helps.. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Those two problems most likely aren't related, so I recommend you [edit] the part about freezing and slowness out and ask it as another question. As for the repository info, can you run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal and copy-paste the error message at the end into your question? I suspect it's a broken source.

Comment: Ok, tried to paste the whole list after get-up but too long so i will post as much as i can here are the ones at the bottom of the list=(W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lestcape/cinnamon/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: Are you connected to a network? if you google cats, do you get cat pictures? The hard drive thing is unrelated, you might take that out.  The contents of your HD are also unrelated,  and 18% usage is literally nothing.  Your question may do well to focus on the repo / network problem.  show us this command output: `ip addr show `

Comment: yes im connected and i do get the pics when i google cats

Comment: will edit original post, is it safe to put my ip addr info here? and should i put the whole list i get after running get -update? cuz its really long, and what is IGN, GET, & HIT infront of certain lines?

Comment: Sorry for the many questions, im kinda new to this.. should i put the info i get after running the ip addr show & get-update command on my original post?? @Zacharee1

Comment: That error that you posted just means that source is no longer active, or is invalid. See if you can find it using the Software Center's source manager and remove it. You'll be good.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have many errors when running get update, if i can add it to the original post would it be possible you can skim thru it?(is it safe to post that info).. i have things that say saucey salamander which i know is old version plus UTOPIC AND VIVID AND PRIVATE PPA ETC..

Comment: Oh wow. You have a lot of stuff left over. Use the Software Center's source manager to just remove any source that has the old names.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one more question can i just wipe my HDD clean and just do a fresh install? and will that clear the partitions cuz i have no idea whats on the partitions. sorry for the many questions @Zacharee1

Comment: If you are willing to lose your data, definitely do a reinstall. I avoided recommending that because most people have important stuff they want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of the recent ubuntu versions:
Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)
Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Please read the "Technical details about this PPA" [here](https://launchpad.net/~lestcape/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon).

If you merge several repositories for several different Ubuntu version, then you really can ask to yourself: why I don't had a lot of problems before?